# Angular object on page load

Tags: angularjs

I have a map built on angular. https://vineyardcincinnati.com/nigeria-map

I have a field updating based on the google marker clicked. Is there a way to initialize an angular object based on the page load? The content box is currently blank until the user sends JSON data based on a click event.

Here is my angular code:

```
$scope.map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), mapOptions);

$scope.markers = [];

var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
maxWidth: 200
});

var createMarker = function (info){

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: $scope.map,
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(info.lat, info.long),
        title: info.location,
        image: info.img,
        date: info.date,
        quote: info.quote
    });

    marker.content = '<div class="infoWindowContent">' + info.desc + '</div>';

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function(){
        infoWindow.setContent(marker.content);
        $scope.selectedMarker = marker;
        $scope.$apply();
        infoWindow.open($scope.map, marker);
    });

    $scope.markers.push(marker);

}  

for (i = 0; i < cities.length; i++){
    createMarker(cities[i]);
}

$scope.openInfoWindow = function(e, selectedMarker){
    e.preventDefault();
    google.maps.event.trigger(selectedMarker, 'click');
}

});
```

Here is my view

```
<div id="containter" ng-app="mapsApp" ng-controller="MapCtrl">

<div id="map"></div>

<div id="class">
     <h1> {{selectedMarker.title}}</h1>
     <p>{{selectedMarker.quote}}</p>
     <p>Completed {{selectedMarker.date}}</p>
</div>

</div>
```

Comment: Tried the ng-init directive ?

Answer (score 0):

Use $timeout from inside your directive's controller:

```
$timeout(function() { 
     // initialize plugin on load here...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `module.run`.

```
angular.module('myModule',[])
.run(function($rootScope){
  $rootScope.selected = "foo";
  // code runs on module init
}
```